# how to collect specific field in spring query creation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I created spring api for user they can use the oldpassword and company to get the new username and password. How can we select specific fields in Spring query creation?

I created repo like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    List<User> findUserByCompanyAndOldUsername(String company, String oldUsername);

}
```

and I return the data of my row tables like this:

```
@GetMapping("/index")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUserByCompanyAndOldUsername(@RequestParam String company,
                                                                 @RequestParam String oldUsername){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.findUserByCompanyAndOldUsername(company, oldUsername), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and the result:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "oldUsername": "FDIFSA00101",
    "customerKey": "FRIFSA00101",
    "company": "FRI",
    "newUser": "FSA00101",
    "oldPassword": "$2a$10$36dHjzxiEpvrjVPE6OhzkeiinNZt3/H7SjpKEI/LHqBAJ0MAZD6O2",
    "newPassword": "Password"
  }
```

I only need the newUser and newPassword data for me to display on the thymeleaf html page not the all data. how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the fields while deserializing to your dto. You can use:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(value = "field_name")
```

Use these annotations above the fields or before their getter methods for which you don't want to see any values in response. It should work.

Note: for camelCase names, follow this style: `firstName` to `first_name`